# Styling a control template in Silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-5.0, controltemplate

I'm looking at using the [Silverlight Menu Control](http://slmenu.codeplex.com/) from Codeplex. It's functionally very good but I'd like to restyle the appearance. Is it possible to do this without just making a new copy of the template and changing a few properties? Here's an example from the generic "theme" that comes with the control:

```
<Style TargetType="GenericControl:MenuBar">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GenericControl:MenuBar">
                <Canvas x:Name="LayoutRootMB">
                    <StackPanel Height="25" 
                                x:Name="baseRectMB" 
                                Canvas.Left="0" 
                                Canvas.Top="0"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </Canvas>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I'd like to change, say, `HorizontalAlignment` to `Stretch` (for the sake of argument -- never mind if it'll actually accomplish anything useful). Is there any way to tell XAML (in XAML, not in C#) that I want to do something to `baseRectMB`?

`baseRectMB` is named in a `TemplatePartAttribute` on class `MenuBar`.

I assume I can simply copy the existing template and alter it, though I haven't gotten that working yet either.

Comment: Have you tried Expression blend ? It is powerful tool to edit XAML elements.

Comment: @NareshRavlani That was the first thing I tried. That's how I found out that Blend in VS2012 doesn't support Silverlight.

Comment: Yes but you can install blend + sketchflow preview to get this done. However you can always go for expression blend 4 as it is standalone installation. i am not sure for this, but you can give it a try.